# F# counting repeats in a list

Tags: recursion, f#

In F# is there a way to map for example `[2;2;2;2;5;5;5;7;7]` to `[4,3,2]` without recursion and without mutable? I looked through the Array and List members and found Reduce but that does not seem to help.

Comment: Why recursion and mutable restriction? I could whip out a for loop and a ref cell but that's not conceptually different

Comment: I thought it would be cleaner and shorter. Not sure what you mean by "but that's not conceptually different".

Comment: Just nitpicking, but `[4,3,2]` is a tuple -- I think you meant `[4;3;2]` :)

Answer (score 11):

You can implement it quickly using [`Seq.countBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340317.aspx). Using F# interactive, it looks like this:

```
> [2;2;2;2;5;5;5;7;7] |> Seq.countBy id;;
val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(2, 4); (5, 3); (7, 2)]
```

If you only want the counts (and not the values which were repeated), you can just pipe the result into `Seq.map`:

```
> [2;2;2;2;5;5;5;7;7] |> Seq.countBy id |> Seq.map snd;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [4; 3; 2]
```

Note that you can implement this using `Seq.groupBy`, but `Seq.countBy` is much more efficient: `Seq.groupBy` consumes more memory because it has to store all of the groups, whereas `Seq.countBy` stores just one `int` (the counter) for each key in the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[2;2;2;2;5;5;5;7;7] |> Seq.groupBy id |> Seq.map (snd >> Seq.length)
```

`Seq.groupBy id` collects the list up into groups of equal elements - using the identity function `id` means that the elements of the sequence are used directly as the "keys" for the equality check. This gives us a sequence of the original elements paired up with the repeats:

```
 seq [(2, seq [2; 2; 2; 2]); (5, seq [5; 5; 5]); (7, seq [7; 7])]
```

Then for each of the inner sequences, we use `snd` to just get the sequence of repeats, and `Seq.length` to get its length. `>>` is the composition operator that applies the first function and then the second.